# Changing a comma delimited csv file to a double quoted comma delimited csv file PHP

Tags: php

I have a csv file that I'm trying to change from comma delimitted to double quoted comma delimited with PHP and I don't even know where to begin. 
Here are the first few lines of the file:

```
ID,LastName,FirstName,Grade

13,Donahue,Apple,5

21,Westen,Craig,4
```

I tried using a **str_replace** but it doesn't add the " to the beginning or the end of the row.

Comment: I don't think it should add it to the end and beginning of the rows if you want to replace commas with quotes. Each line is a different row

Comment: Well show us the code you tried and we can fix it

Comment: So... add a quote to the beginning and end of each row?